# Can I remove/disable all Share functionality by removing share.war file?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

In my new project we are going to use Alfresco as back-end and Angular as front-end, so we wish to remove/disable Share completely if possible. I read somewhat in internet and some people just removed share.war file. Is this safe? Is it the correct way for doing this? Will any errors appear in the future because of this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just remove it.  You will of course,  not have the fancy front end.  But if you are just using it for back end stuff it will be fine.  There are no dependencies, and you should get no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely you can remove share.war as it is completely separate from alfresco.war. It won't give you any error. refer [this](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/remove-apps-install.html)

Answer (score 0):

As said above, yes you can live with only alfresco war installed. Were I work we don't use share, we only use the repo via its api.

But keep in mind that if you have a recent version of alfresco, you don't have access to the repo UI any-more and share UI give you access to lot of repo config you can change without restart. I would keep share, disable all of its service (properties in alfresco-global that enable services for share; like the thumb preview generation, swf transformers, activity feed etc...) and keep it safe private to your admins.

Comment: Yes, we don't want actually deleted it but disable it. Could you please assist me disabling cron of both alfresco and share?

Comment: Yes sure, I'll check this evening on a recent repo, what version are you using?

Comment: You can redefine those cron in /shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties and edit share cron (I'll list them later there are not many it is mainly properties for services)
alfresco.cron=* * * * * ? 2099
system.thumbnail.generate=false
activities.feed.notifier.enabled=false
googledocs.enabled=false
...
The exact config depend on your version of Alfresco
Then you can follow this guide to remove what you don't need:
https://fr.slideshare.net/LuisCabaceira/alfresco-tuning-part1 https://fr.slideshare.net/LuisCabaceira/alfresco-tuning-part2